# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Fast.Models.Reviews>'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
string updatedVotes = string.Empty;
updatedVotes = updatedVotes.Substring(0, updatedVotes.Length - 1);

db.Entry(sch).State = EntityState.Modified;
sch.Rates = updatedVotes;
db.SaveChanges();
```

But the code doesn't compile because of the error you're seeing up there, and I've yet to understand why exactly. Any help anyone?

Comment: `updatedVotes` is of type `string`. `sch.Rates` is of type `ICollection<Fast.Models.Reviews>`. You can't assign variables of different types to each other like that. That's C# 101.

Answer (score 0):

updatedVotes is a string, but you are trying to assign it to Rates (Which I assume is a collection of Fast.Models.Reviews).

You have the wrong types. A cat cannot be converted to a dog, therefore a string cannot be converted to System.Collections.Generic.ICollection

Comment: What if evolution happened like: **Cat : Dog : Animal** . Who knows ;)

Answer (score 0):

The error message pretty much tells you what is going on. On this line:

```
sch.Rates = updatedVotes;
```

Rates is an `ICollection<Review>` whereas updatedVotes is a `string`. You can't assign a `string` to an `ICollection<Review>`